# Keep encoded link after order is completed in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

Hey guys is there a way to keep encoded link after order is completed in wordpress?

It looks good in cart and checkout:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ads9G.png)

But not so good in order review and admin order review
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPbDF.png)

I use encodeURIComponent to encode every url param:
[My example link that i generate](https://isodos.lt/pinigines-stilius/?l=0&tf1inner=Hello%26nbsp%3B%3Cimg%20class%3D%22myicnimg%22%20style%3D%22display%3A%20inline%3B%22%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fisodos.lt%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2021%2F04%2F24-Gamta.svg%22%20width%3D%2220%22%20height%3D%2220%22%20%22%3D%22%22%3E)

**EDIT**

Product creation page: https://isodos.lt/produktas/pinigine/ If you want to see order review page you can add it to the cart and test buy it with random name etc.

Btw, i took php code from somewhere, not my code, im not good with php, especially in wordpress

```js
//small example

const graviravimasFinished = document.querySelector("#iconic-engraving-finished");


        if(tf1text === "nerNieko" || tf1text === ""){
            tf1TxtFinal = "";
        }else{
            let txt1TxtEncoded = encodeURIComponent(tf1text);
            tf1TxtFinal = `&tf1inner=${txt1TxtEncoded}`;
        }

tf1TxtFinal = `${tf1TxtFinal}${tf1TopFinal}${tf1LeftFinal}${tf1SizeFinal}${tf1FontFinal}`;
        tf2TxtFinal = `${tf2TxtFinal}${tf2TopFinal}${tf2LeftFinal}${tf2SizeFinal}${tf2FontFinal}`;
        tf3TxtFinal = `${tf3TxtFinal}${tf3TopFinal}${tf3LeftFinal}${tf3SizeFinal}${tf3FontFinal}`;

    
    graviravimasFinished.value = `<a href="https://isodos.lt/pinigines-stilius/?l=0${tf1TxtFinal}${tf2TxtFinal}${tf3TxtFinal}${imgFinal}${imgTopFinal}${imgLeftFinal}">Stilius</a>`;
```

```html
<?php

function iconic_output_engraving_field() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_id() !== 5296 ) {
        return;
    }

    ?>

    <!-- Graviravimo tekstas -->
    <div style="padding-bottom: 10px" class="iconic-engraving-field">
                   
  <!-- Info -->
  <input style="display: none;" type="text" id="iconic-engraving-finished" name="iconic-engraving-finished">

        
  </div>
                    
<?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'iconic_output_engraving_field', 10 );

/**
 * Add engraving text to cart item.
 *
 * @param array $cart_item_data
 * @param int   $product_id
 * @param int   $variation_id
 *
 * @return array
 */
function iconic_add_engraving_text_to_cart_item( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    $engraving_text = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'iconic-engraving-finished' );
    

    if ( empty( $engraving_text ) ) {
        return $cart_item_data;
    }

    $cart_item_data['iconic-engraving-finished'] = $engraving_text;

    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'iconic_add_engraving_text_to_cart_item', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Display engraving text in the cart.
 *
 * @param array $item_data
 * @param array $cart_item
 *
 * @return array
 */
function iconic_display_engraving_text_cart( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( empty( $cart_item['iconic-engraving-finished'] ) ) {
        return $item_data;
    }

    $item_data[] = array(
        'key'     => __( 'Graviravimas', 'iconic-finished' ),
        'value'   =>  $cart_item['iconic-engraving-finished'] ,
        'display' => '',
    );

    return $item_data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'iconic_display_engraving_text_cart', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Add engraving text to order.
 *
 * @param WC_Order_Item_Product $item
 * @param string                $cart_item_key
 * @param array                 $values
 * @param WC_Order              $order
 */
function iconic_add_engraving_text_to_order_items( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( empty( $values['iconic-engraving-finished'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $item->add_meta_data( __( 'Graviravimas', 'iconic-finished' ), $values['iconic-engraving-finished'] );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'iconic_add_engraving_text_to_order_items', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Comment: Edited my code. I think it has somehting to do with how wordpress  displays code in order review and admin order view. You should 'buy' the item so you can see order review page with bad code..